# Is there a Player's Club leaderboard?

Tags: tiny-tower-vegas

I have searched for a Player's Club leaderboard for a few weeks now and the closest I got was [a very outdated list on the AppCheaters site](http://appcheaters.com/tiny-tower-vegas-players-club-share/).

I also saw that one comment on [this TouchArcade page](http://toucharcade.com/2014/09/03/tiny-tower-vegas-guide-tips/) mentioned a leaderboard, but they provided no link and that was two years ago.

Is there a way to access a list of the team rankings within the game itself? Am I just missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Menu -> Players Club -> Under CLUB TOTAL, where it says your current club is #XX IN THE WORLD, tap that button and you can see the 7 rankings centered around your club rank as well as the top clubs

Comment: I didn't think to tap on the rank. It didn't look like a button to me.